# TFS: How to reset BuildDetail.BuildNumber?

Tags: tfs, build

Simply, I have created multiple builds in Main Branch. However, BuildDetails.BuildNumber is same and incrementing.
I know if I branch my code, it would reset to 1.

**Q:** Is it possible to reset this number for each build without creating branches?

**Update:** The only option I find up till now is to save my BuildNumber in Version.txt, checked into TFS repository. Checkout this during build, get the number, increment it, use it in versioning, and Checkin the file. 
 However, still looking for some better solution.

Answer (score 1):

A bit unclear on what you're after. Let me try to explain how build numbers work:

Build "numbers" are generated using the `Build Number Format` build definition parameter, which by default is `$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)`. The `$(Rev:.r)` part automatically increments, and resets back to `1` when the day change (all this happens separately for each build definition). AFAIK there's no way to reset `$(Rev:.r)`, nor should there be, because that would case multiple builds with the same build number, which would be confusing.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for quick reply. That's is why I was referring to BuildDetail.BuildNumber, which is unique through out the builds in one Team Project. However, it resets if code is branched, as builds for branches is different from trunk... But I need to reset to specific number for each build somehow.

Comment: Still unclear. You have build definition `Trunk`, which produces build numbers `Trunk_20150715.1`, `Trunk_20150715.2` etc. You branch the code into a branch, create a new build definition `Branch`, which produces build `Branch_20150715.1`, but you want `Branch_20150715.3`?

Comment: That build number is coming from Build Definition, which is like $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.rr). I would like to use Internal build number which can get from BuildDetails.BuildNumber, may have to edit Build Template for that. But this is not editable and can't be reset :(

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having your version number stored in source control you can use the build number generated by TFS.

If you change the format from "$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)" to something like "$(BuildDefinitionName)_1.5.$(YY)$(ddd)$(Rev:.r)" then you can set it as part of the build definition.

You can then parse out this number and use it to version your application, and change it how you like by branch, or whatever.

Comment: We want complete control over our version numbers. Incrementing in proper sequence and also want to reset it to any value, whenever required.

Comment: This will allow you to do that, however any value is not allowed as you should not have identical values. The build name let's you do that.

Comment: The only two options are Build Name or .txt file.